# Transition of labels in D3.js: Rename label names on change and transition smoothly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am a beginner in d3 and I am creating a changing barchart with D3.js. I came so far that I can create the barchart, change the dataset when clicking on my radio buttons, and change the axises.

Now what I don't get to work is changing the name of the labels on the x and y axis. I also don't get it to work that my label ticks transition smoothly with my bars, they just change abruptly.

For my label names I was trying to remove the names and then add it again in my on change function. But that only displays the new text right from the start:

Appending to the svg:

```
 //y-axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
        .text("Crazy label name for axis");
```

And then removing it and adding it anew in my change function:

```
 svg.select(".y.label").remove();

         svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
        .text("new crazy text");
```

Also I can't get my tick-names (or the label names for each bar) transition smoothly with my bars.

Can anyone help me out? Very much appreciated!

Here is the full code as well as example data:

```
 d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function(d) {
      selectDataset.call(this, d);
    });

    function selectDataset(d) {
      let value = this.value;
      if (value === "heat") {
        change(datasetTotal, value, "Default text");
      } else if (value === "cool") {
        change(datasetOption1, value, "Text 2");
      } else if (value === "area") {
        change(datasetOption2, value, "Text 3");
      }
}

    var margin = {
            top: (parseInt(d3.select('.area-heat-cool').style('height'), 10) / 20),
            right: (parseInt(d3.select('.area-heat-cool').style('width'), 10) / 20),
            bottom: (parseInt(d3.select('.area-heat-cool').style('height'), 10) / 20),
            left: (parseInt(d3.select('.area-heat-cool').style('width'), 10) / 5)
        },
        width = parseInt(d3.select('.area-heat-cool').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = parseInt(d3.select('.area-heat-cool').style('height'), 10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var div = d3.select(".area-heat-cool").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([height, 0], .2, 0.5)
        .paddingInner(0.1);

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(x);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(y);

    var svg = d3.select(".area-heat-cool").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    //x-axis
    svg.append("text")
          .attr("class", "x label")
          .attr("data-default", "text2_contact2")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("x", width)
          .attr("y", height - 6)
          .text("Default text");

    //y-axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
        .text("Text of y Axis");


    d3.select("input[value=\"heat\"]").property("checked", true);
    change(datasetTotal);

    function change(dataset, optionSelect, textselect) {

        y.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {
            return d.label;
        }));
        x.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

        svg.select(".y.axis").remove();
        svg.select(".x.axis").remove();
        // svg.select(".y.label").remove();

        d3.select(".x.label").text(textselect).transition().duration(1000) ;

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
            .attr("x", 50)
            .attr("dx", ".1em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Option %");


        var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(dataset, function(d) {
                return d.label;
            });

        var barExit = bar.exit().remove();

        var barEnter = bar.enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class", "bar");

        var barRects = barEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(0);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.label);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

        var barTexts = barEnter.append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return x(d.value) + 10;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d.label) + y.bandwidth() / 2;
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });


        barRectUpdate = bar.select("rect")
                  .transition()
                  .duration(3050)
                  .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return x(0);
                  })
                  .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return y(d.label);
                  })
                  .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return x(d.value);
                  })
                  .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
                  .style('fill', function () {
                    if (optionSelect === "heat") {
                      return '#A12D24'
                    } else if (optionSelect === "cool") {
                      return '#668BA4'
                    } else if (optionSelect === "area") {
                      return 'lightgrey'
                    }
                  });

        var barTextsUpdate = bar.select("text")
              .transition()
              .duration(3050)
              .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.value) + 10;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d.label) + y.bandwidth() / 2;
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });

    }
```

And data looks like

```
data1 = [{label: "example 1", value: 156}
{label: "example 2", value: 189}
{label: "example 3", value: 234}
{label: "example 4", value: 345}
{label: "example 5", value: 346}
{label: "example 6", value: 456}
{label: "example 7", value: 489}
{label: "example 8", value: 567}]; 


data2 = [{label: "example 1", value: 23}
{label: "example 2", value: 211}
{label: "example 3", value: 45}
{label: "example 4", value: 64}
{label: "example 5", value: 95}
{label: "example 6", value: 32}
{label: "example 7", value: 0}
{label: "example 8", value: 234}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing the DOM elements for the text and not updating them. If there is a need to remove them then you can fade out the text and remove them at the end as such `d3.select("text").transition().duration(300).style("opacity","0").on("end", () => { d3.select("text").removeAll() });`

but I suggest that you reuse the labels and just update their content using the same `d3.select("").transition().duration(300)` way

Comment: thank you so much Cornel! I will try this tomorrow when I'm back at my pc and let you know!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was not on my pc the weekend. With your help Cornel I managed now to transition the text labels like this: ```d3.select(".x.label").text(textselect).transition().duration(1000) ;``` I pass the textvalue in the function. My problem now is that the defaultvalue doesn't show. It only shows when I click on the radio buttons but not in the beginning. (I updated the code). Do you have any idea why that might be? Thank you again

Comment: I would make the default showing on an else branch rather than if one ```let value = this.value;
      if (value === "cool") {
        change(datasetOption1, value, "Text 2");
      } else if (value === "area") {
        change(datasetOption2, value, "Text 3");
      } else { change(datasetTotal, value, "Default text"); } ```

Comment: thanks!! unfortunately it still doesn't show me the default value like this.... I also think it is weird that it doesn't show because I append it before I call the function, right?! And without the function it'd show the default

Comment: Just noticed - ```selectDataset``` is defined in the ```d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function(d) {``` listener function. Try to extract it outside the function and call it by default. Using it in a listener will be executed only on value change and not by default

Comment: uh yes I see what you mean.... With extracting it and calling it by default you mean putting it in a separate function and the call this function?

Comment: yup - you shoud try that

Comment: can't really get it to work with extracting it. Also I want it to trigger the event on change, so shouldn't there be an option to set the default value? Anyways I want to be mindful with your time, so I'll move that to a separate question if I can't get it to work soon. Thanks so much for helping me out with the transitions!!

Comment: What if you do this: instead of calling `change(datasetTotal);` call: `change(datasetTotal, undefined, 'default text');`

Comment: that also gives me the same behaviour unfortunately

Comment: try to create an observable (https://observablehq.com) or a block on (https://blockbuilder.org) with sample data and I will fix it for you

Comment: ok did it. can you access this? https://blockbuilder.org/Micromegass/faa6108e9bdc8f2ff1e92d06198e4978